# Eclipse getter/setter format

Tags: eclipse

Does anyone know of an Eclipse plug-in or method to get Eclipse to generate getter/setters on one line like this:

```
public String getAbc() { return abc; }
```

Instead of

```
public String getAbc() {
   return abc;
}
```

I'm on Eclipse v. 3.2.2.

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't know how to make Eclipse generate them in the format you want, but you could do a search/replace using these regular expressions after the methods are generated:

Find:

```
(?m)((?:public |private |protected )?[\w$]+) (get|set|is)([\w$]+)\(([\w$]+(?:\[\])? [\w$]+)?\) \{\s+(return [\w$]+;|this.[\w$]+ = [\w$]+;)\s+\}
```

Replace by:

```
$1 $2$3($4) { $5 }
```

This expression will transform the generated getters and setters to be one line. Don't worry about running it with a mixture of transformed and newly generated methods; it will work just fine.

Comment: Thanks Hosam.  I'd ideally prefer a way to have Eclipse just generate the getters on a single line without having to perform a second step.

Comment: I would say that your RegEx does work well.  One thing - seems like in my version/config of Eclipse, the "replace by" expression needs to use dollar signs instead of the back slash: $1 $2$3($4) { $5 }

Comment: Yes @Marcus. I'm using Eclipse 3.4.1, but it appears that previous versions required the use of '$' instead of '\'. The latest version supports both. I'll edit my answer. Thanks for the information.

Comment: If you find a way to give a shortcut to this search/replace operation, I would be thankful if you could share it. Thank you.

Comment: This is the best solution I've found.  Thanks Hosam.

Comment: @Marcus - I think you might find my answer a little simpler!

Comment: (?m)((?:public |private |protected )?[\w$]+) (get|set|is)([\w$]+)\(((final )?[\w$]+ [\w$]+)?\) \{\s+(return [\w$]+;|this.[\w$]+ = [\w$]+;)\s+\} and replace with $1 $2$3($4) { $6 } this supports "is" getters and "final" parameters

Comment: @Olexandr: Thanks for your help. I've incorporated the `is`-style getter in my answer, but `final` setter parameters are too rare in my experience, and would make the expression even more complex. There are also `final` and `synchronized` modifiers for the method itself, but I've left them out too. Nevertheless, thank you for your input.

Comment: @LeventeHolló Thanks for your suggestion for incorporating generics in the expression. It would have been nice to have it as a comment. I'll test it and then merge it.

Comment: I did a little edit to make it work too with a new line after the closing `)` of the method, because I have the formatter set up like this.
Edit: `(?m)((?:public |private |protected )?[\w$]+) (get|set|is)([\w$]+)\(([\w$]+ [\w$]+)?\)\s+\{\s+(return [\w$]+;|this.[\w$]+ = [\w$]+;)\s+\}`

Comment: another thing to notice, Arrays are not supported in this regular expression string, I'm not familiar with RegEx so I don't know how to implement this...

Comment: @Dediqated I've tried to add support for arrays into the expression (although I haven't tested it).

Answer (score 4):

I think matching generics is important as well, so the correct regexp is:

```
(?m)((?:public |private |protected )?[\w\<\>$]+) (get|set|is)([\w$]+)\(([\w\<\>$]+ [\w$]+)?\) \{\s+(return [\w$]+;|this.[\w$]+ = [\w$]+;)\s+\}
```

Comment: This should probably have been a comment on Hosam Aly's answer, not an answer by itself.

Answer (score 2):

As a variation of the regexp replacement approach, the following reformats the whitespace so that setters are followed by a blank line, but getters are not.

Find:

```
(\s(?:get|is|set)\w+\([^)]*\))\s*\{\s*(?:([^=;}]+;)\s*\}\s*(\R)|([^=;}]+=[^=;}]+;)\s*\}\s*(\R))
```

Replace by:

```
$1 { $2$4 } \R$5
```

Results in:

```
int getTotal() { return total; } 
void setTotal(int total) { this.total = total; } 

List<String> getList() { return list; } 
void setList(List<String> list) { this.list = list; } 

Map.Entry<String, Integer> getEntry() { return entry; } 
void setEntry(Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry) { this.entry = entry; }
```

It's a minor aesthetic thing, but I figured that if you're looking for an answer to this question, then you're probably (almost) as anal as me ;-)

I know my regexp conditions are not as strict as those of @Hosam, but I haven't experienced any "false positive" replacements.

Comment: awesome, just what i searching for!

Answer (score 1):

Java code formatting in Eclipse does not differentiate between getters/setters and any other methods in a class. So this cannot be done by built-in eclipse formatting.

You will need either to:

1. run a search/replace with the aforementioned regex
2. get en external plugin like [PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/) or [CheckStyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/) and enforce a regex rule based on previous option

Answer (score 1):

You can use fast code plug-in to generate this kind of getter setters. The details are given here : http://fast-code.sourceforge.net/documentation.htm#create-new-field.

[image: Create Variable]

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to post as a comment to the designated answer, but I don't seem to be able to.

I modified Hosam Aly's answer to work with generic and inner types of the form:

```
List<X>
```

and

```
Map.Entry
```

The revised regular expression search string is:

```
(?m)((?:public |private |protected )?[\w\.\<\>$]+) (get|set|is)([\w$]+)\(([\w\.\<\>$]+ [\w$]+)?\) \{\s+(return [\w\.\<\>$]+;|this.[\w$]+ = [\w$]+;)\s+\}
```

This regular expression allows for angle brackets and a dot in the type.

For example:

```
public List<String> getStringList()
```

and

```
public void setStringList(List<String> list)
```

and

```
public Map.Entry getEntry ()
```

And the replace string is the same as before:

```
$1 $2$3($4) { $5 }
```